# UI testing for react native apps

Tags: user-interface, testing, react-native, ui-testing

i am currently working on a UI automated testing project.

my job is to do UI automated testing on applications built via react-native.

the problem is that react-native doesn't provide resource-id.

i tried nativeID, and testID, and it didn't work out.

i tried accessibilityLabel but this is not the way to do it, because it assigns to the content-descp: which is used by the blind mode.

i tried cavy which is an integrated-ui testing tool, but it's very new, and there is not much support, plus it's not quit developped yet.

i tried selendroid, but i am facing some problems while loading the app in the local selendroid server, i think it has something to do with react native.

any help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the project I’m working on right now, we are using Calabash for both Android and iOS. `testID` works with Calabash like this: 
If you have a view with testID `some-id`, then you can query for it in calabash with query string `”* marked: some-id”`

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios

I have also heard people having success with Appium, which is quite similar I think.

Comment: the only thing that showed up in uiautomatorviewer is the accessibilityLabel,  and it showed as content-descp. i have another question for you: when you discover a flaw in your app, do you have to fix your app and then do assembleRelease (in cmd)? isn't this process so painfully slow??

Comment: Are you talking about the release process or just to build a release build for UI test? There’s no way around it for UI test in my opinion. I think UI tests are acceptance tests and not necessarily main tests to find bugs. We still focus on unit tests and integration tests for development and UI test is run less frequently for acceptance testing.

Comment: OK thank you so much for your help, it's just that my boss told me to do UI testing, this is part of my internship, and i don't really have much of a choice. but anyway thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add AccessbiltiyLabel so that you will be able to automate via 
driver.findElement(by.accessibility("id");